# How to get rid of error message on ssh login --> "setterm: terminal xterm does not support --blength"

Tags: bash, terminal, putty, arch-linux, xterm

Whenever I ssh into my **arch linux** box I get this error message:

```
setterm: terminal xterm does not support --blength
```

Also when executing:

```
$ sudo su -
```

Interestingly not when using

```
$ sudo su
```

I have sifted through various man pages trying to find where this terminal attribute is being set. Those included `setterm` and `terminfo`. 
I went even so far doing

`find / -type f -iname "terminfo" -exec grep -i blength {} \;`

That returned 0 results. Also looked into `/etc/.bashrc`and `/etc/bash.basrc`but nowhere I discovered anything that invokes `setterm`or even includes `*blength*` in its statement.

This issue really just is a minor nuisance but I find it highly irritating simply because I don't like seeing error messages of a system that is in the state `running` when queried with `systemctl status --system`.
In addition I made sure PuTTY (using SuperPuTTY as its frontend) is not passing in any commands.
I would really appreciate some pointers on this issue. Thank you very much.

Comment: I am getting this error every time I create a shell after upgrading from Ubuntu 14.04 to Ubuntu 16.04. I tried deleting the corresponding parts of /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/setterm, but that didn't help.

Comment: to help narrow down, you could try one or more of these:

* disabling X11 forwarding `ssh -o ForwardX11=no`
* rename .bash_profile
* rename .bashrc

Comment: oh, and you could try setting your terminal settings to use a visual bell instead of an audible one.  In any event setterm wants `-blength`, not `--blength`. /etc/profile and /etc/profile.d/* are also possible ways to get terminal settings entered, as well as stty.

Comment: @strobelight Didn't rename files for worries over messing things up but I did looked into every file thats named `bash_profile` but couldn't grep `blength` anywhere. What is the significance of disabling X11 forwarding ?

Comment: "disabling X11" was simply something else to try.... one less thing for ssh to do in case it was an ssh problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oh dear after long last I found it thanks to one of the comments of [strobelight](https://superuser.com/users/642390/strobelight) pointing out that possible candidates for the setting to look into are in `/etc/profile.d/`

> [..] /etc/profile and /etc/profile.d/* are also possible ways to get terminal settings entered [..]

I then promptly did just that with `grep -e "blength" /etc/profile.d/*`. 
The output of which was:

```
disable-beep.sh:setterm -blength 0
```

So I first commented it out, logged out, back in again and **the error was gone**.

I then looked at the command a second time since it didn't have double dashes `--` but just a single one.

So I assumed since commenting out the line fixes the error¹, the command `setterm` expects key value pairs and handles the dashes itself or `insert another implementation detail` but in any case I have to provide the command as such:

```
setterm blength 0
```

Said, done, saved, relogged and the error is still gone and the bell most likely stays silent.
Again wouldn't have found this without [strobelight`s](https://superuser.com/users/642390/strobelight) comment.

**¹** but probably enables the bell again, which I couldn't tell since I am RDP'd into the machine thats running the ssh session w/o forwarding sounds - why the additional layer you might ask, to which I answer corporate notebook w/o rights to do shit, which yes is stupid considering my job

Comment: glad I helped point the way!  So many flavors of linux and not all have the same scripts.

Comment: It's interesting that you used `blength` instead of `-blength` or `--blength` and it fixed your problem. Where/how can I find documentation about that behavior? I have been searching and couldn't find. Thanks to this I also solved similar message, by replacing
`setterm -blank 0` with `setterm blank 0` in .bashrc file.

Comment: @mikl, `setterm` simply ignores that **incorrect** input. So it's effectively means a no-op.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Turns out to be setting in my own `.bashrc`. After commenting out the line:

```
setterm -blength 0
```

I am not getting the error message any more.

Comment: That's the funny thing. I do also faintly remember setting that value myself way in the past at some point. I logged on as root and did `find / -type f -name "*ashr*" -exec grep -e "blength" {} \;` but didn't come up with anything. Not sure what other files might be candidates to look in. Any ideas?

Comment: well, you could try `'*ashr*'` since `"*ashr*"` would expand to every file in the current directory containing an "ashr" instead of what you really wanted which is to find all files with containing "ashr".  Basically you don't want the asterisk to expand so it needs to be in single quotes.

Comment: @strobelight Probably should look into command expansion for this but I still don't get how those two commands differ. I feel even your explanation basically says both commands are equivalent. Would appreciate if you could elaborate or just provide a few links to this topic. Sorry for being so daft. ;)